# InvalidArgumentError in Keras Embedding layer due to a negative index lookup

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am receiving an `InvalidArgumentError` while trying to train a deep learning model implemented in Keras. I have searched similar issues in Keras and TensorFlow, however my error message seems to be unusual due to the index that could not be found. Below is the error message.

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.**InvalidArgumentError**: indices[427,9] = **-2147483648** is not in [0, 38545)
>   [[Node: time_distributed_1/Gather = Gather[Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT, validate_indices=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](embeddings/read, time_distributed_1/Cast)]]

I am using Python 3.5.2 with TensorFlow version is 1.4.1, and Keras version 2.1.5.

As you can notice, not only the index being sought is negative, it is actually equal to -2^31. (i.e. the lowest 32-bit signed integer value)

Below is the code I used to prepare the model.

```
import numpy
from keras.layers import Embedding, Bidirectional, LSTM, TimeDistributed
from keras_contrib.layers import CRF

# Form embedding layer's weight matrix
V = len(word_to_index) + 1  # V = 38545
embedding_weights = numpy.zeros((V, N))
for word, index in word_to_index.items():
    embedding_weights[index, :] = word_vec_dict[word]

embedding_layer = Embedding(V, N,
                            weights=[embedding_weights], mask_zero=True)

model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(embedding_layer,
                          input_shape=(C, U)))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Bidirectional(LSTM(M // 2, return_sequences=True))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(GlobalMaxPooling1D()))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(H // 2, return_sequences = True), merge_mode='concat'))
crf = CRF(num_tags, sparse_target=True)
model.add(crf)
model.compile('adam', loss = crf.loss_function, metrics=[crf.accuracy])
```

The data being fed to this model has the dimensions `(C, U, N)` and is of type `int`. (i.e. excluding the batch size dimension `B`) Simply put, each sample in a batch is a conversation of length `C`. Each conversation consists of utterances with fixed length `U`. Finally, each utterance is made up of `N` positive indices. (i.e. indices of the relevant words in the vocabulary)

I even checked the entire dataset (after it is converted to indices) using simple for loops and could not find any index value outside the range `[0, 38545)`. Why does such an index loop for `-2^31` occur during training?

Comment: @DanielMöller As my question mentions, I checked my entire dataset for out-of-range values using for loops to iterate over the data. There wasn't any. Also, not only that, I actually printed the data into a text file and using a text editor I searched for the minus sign character `-`. Couldn't find any.

Comment: 38545 is greater than the maximum int 16 value. Are you sure all your model layers, data arrays, etc. are int32? There lower bound values in Keras can usually appear if something overflows...

Comment: @DanielMöller I form my training validation and testing batches by populating an initially empty `numpy` array of size `(B, C, U)` as follows: `numpy.empty(shape = (B, C, U), dtype=int)`. Its `dtype` is `int64`. As to the rest of the model, I am not sure how I can enforce `int64`, as there aren't any parameters for that. Also, the error statement seems to mention that the error occurs specifically in the first layer of the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. I was using batch generation while training the model, and I left a portion of the input array uninitialized within the batch generator function.

I am unclear as to why the index being looked up was -2147483648, exactly. However, I think, as the uninitialized portion of the array contained values that are greater than the vocabulary size, and even the boundaries of a 32-bit integer for that matter, it caused an undefined behavior.

After I properly initialized the entire batch input accordingly, the issue was solved. Below is a somewhat simplified version of the batch generator function I used. The added initialization section has a comment over it, to highlight what is narrated above.

```
def batch_generator(dataset_x, dataset_y, tag_indices, mini_batch_list, C, U,
                    num_tags, word_index_to_append, tag_index_to_append):
    num_mini_batches = len(mini_batch_list)

    index_list = [x for x in range(num_mini_batches)]
    random.shuffle(index_list)

    k = -1
    while True:
        k = (k + 1) % len(index_list)
        index = index_list[k]
        conversation_indices = mini_batch_list[index]

        num_conversations = len(conversation_indices)
        batch_features = numpy.empty(shape = (num_conversations, C, U),
                                     dtype = int)
        label_list = []

        for i in range(num_conversations):
            utterances = dataset_x[conversation_indices[i]]
            labels = copy.deepcopy(dataset_y[conversation_indices[i]])
            num_utterances = len(utterances)
            num_labels_to_append = max(0, C - len(labels))
            labels += [tag_index_to_append] * num_labels_to_append
            tags = to_categorical(labels, num_tags)
            del labels

            for j in range(num_utterances):
                utterance = copy.deepcopy(utterances[j])
                num_to_append = max(0, U - len(utterance))
                if num_to_append > 0:
                    appendage = [word_index_to_append] * num_to_append
                    utterance += appendage

                batch_features[i][j] = utterance

            # ADDING THE TWO LINES BELOW SOLVED THE ISSUE
            remaining_space = (C - num_utterances, U)
            batch_features[i][num_utterances:] = numpy.ones(remaining_space) *\
                                                 word_index_to_append
            label_list.append(tags)

        batch_labels = numpy.array(label_list)
        yield batch_features, batch_labels
```